# Sending data to Microsoft Word document in Java

Tags: java, sql, forms, api, ms-word

I would like to program a Java program, which sends data to a Microsoft Word file, which contains form textfields.
[Here is the Word-Document](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9t3aa7m5jgmqmhq/Wordform.docx)

So MS Word file with form textfields gets data from a Java program.

I have searched and found an API: http://poi.apache.org/hwpf/
But I am not sure if this is applicable to my problem...

greets

THE-E

Comment: Are you looking for comparison of files? I have same issue! 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411678/docx4j-giving-wrong-result

Comment: No, I want to fill textfields of already existing Word documents. So I have to open the file and replace the textfields with the strings entered in the Java-program. The file should be also opened as read-only, because it is a form which shouldn't be overwritten.
I wanted to get an idea how complicated it is to program and will start the programming in mid-near future.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be able to use the POI to solve your problem.  However, since you are using the .docx format, you need to use XWPF instead of HWPF.  The two do not share a common interface, so you need to make sure to use XWPF from the start.

Any POI project is a work in progress, and there isn't a lot of work done currently to the HWPF project as a whole.  However, you should be able to write the data to a .docx file at the least.

Answer (score 1):

Your docx uses [MERGEFIELD fields](http://webapp.docx4java.org/OnlineDemo/ecma376/WordML/MERGEFIELD.html).

docx4j can process these for you.  See [this sample](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/samples/FieldsMailMerge.java).

I'd suggest you use [v2.8.1.5](http://www.docx4java.org/docx4j/docx4j-2.8.1.5.jar) and 2.8.1's dependencies (from the same dir).